Проектирование таблиц для хранения личных данных в Oracle и Postgres
Допустим, у нас есть таблица Персона с полями Имя, год рождения, пол, а также номер паспорта, номер водительских прав, адрес, место работы и др.
При проектировании в PostgreSQL уместно разбить эту таблицу на две из-за особенности реализации MVCC, например, создать таблицу Person_main с полями Имя, год рождения, пол, номер паспорта, номер водительских прав. А в Person_add положить адрес, место работы и другие поля, которые часто могут меняться.
В Oracle видел такие же решения с разбиением таблиц. Какие плюсы от такого решения в Oracle?

И насколько часто по вашему у людей меняется адрес или там место работы, и более того, они об этом реально сообщают? )  Все перечисленные поля меняются редко с точки зрения БД. Раз в несколько месяцев что-то поменять - это вообще никакой нагрузки на БД. Давайте более реалистичный пример. Но я подозреваю, там что-то другое будет часто меняться, не относящееся к персональным данным. А если речь про "адрес доставки", например, то у одного человека таких адресов может быть несколько и уже даже поэтому их нужно размещать в другой таблице.


Снижение блокировок: В Oracle используется механизм блокировок для обеспечения целостности данных. Если часто изменяются только некоторые поля (например, адрес или место работы), то разбиение таблицы может снизить количество блокировок, так как изменения в одной таблице не будут блокировать доступ к другой.
Упрощение управления данными: Разделение данных на логические группы может упростить управление ими. Например, если адреса и места работы часто обновляются, их можно легко обрабатывать отдельно от более статичных данных.
Оптимизация хранения: В зависимости от типа данных и их использования, можно применять разные механизмы хранения для разных таблиц. Например, можно использовать разные параметры хранения для таблицы с часто изменяемыми данными и для таблицы с редко изменяемыми.
Упрощение миграции и архивирования: Если данные в одной из таблиц становятся устаревшими или их нужно архивировать, это можно сделать более удобно, не затрагивая другие данные.
Безопасность и доступ: Разделение таблиц может позволить более гибко управлять правами доступа. Например, можно ограничить доступ к таблице с чувствительными данными (адресами и местами работы), оставив доступ к основной информации.
Упрощение индексации: Если в одной из таблиц много индексов, это может замедлить операции вставки и обновления. Разделение таблиц может позволить оптимизировать индексацию для каждой из них.


Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?

@Chaos_Sower Забавно, но это не ChatGPT, и вовсе не LLM. При длинных сообщениях у меня выходит такое структурирование текста, если Вы про это

Вообще ответ толковый. А так то если бы это были не персональные данные, а просто какие-то данные, то я видел, когда поступающие данные делили партициями по годам, например. Хотя там свои приколы были в результате, по типу того, что тогда запросы, обращающиеся к нескольким партициям, сильно тормозили, и было выгодно их разбивать на несколько запросов, отдельно обращающиеся к разным партициям, и потом объединять результаты. Ускорение было раз в 10. Так что нужно осознавать и минусы разделения.
